# Navegar hacia otra ventana cuando inicias sesión Angular

Tags: angular, login, eventos

Estoy realizando un proyecto y necesito que una vez inicias sesión te lleve a otra pagina. Pero no logro entender como realizar esta opción. He visto formas de hacerlo con `ngIf` y el `RouterLink` pero no se implementarlo en el código.

Este es el método para hacer login:

```
  loginUsuario(){

    this.loginService.loginUsuario(this.login).subscribe(
      datos => {
        if (datos['resultado'] == "OK"){

          alert( "Has iniciado sesión correctamente" );

        }else{

          alert( "Inicio de Sesión fallido" );
        }
      }
    );
  }
```

Este es el botón donde llama a este metodo:

```
<button type="submit" (click)="loginUsuario()" class="btn btn-login float-right">Entrar</button>
```

¿Como se haría? Si necesitan mas partes del código puedo editar. Gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En tu componente en el constructor puedes inyectar el servicio `Router` que tiene métodos que permiten navegar a los componentes de tu aplicación.

Para poder navegar a los componentes tienes que tener definidas las rutas en tu módulo.

Gracias a la inyección de dependecias que tiene angular cuando definas en el contructor el `Router` este se inyectará en la creación del componente.

```
constructor(private router: Router) {}

loginUsuario() {
  this.loginService.loginUsuario(this.login).subscribe(
    datos => {
      if (datos['resultado'] == "OK") {

        alert("Has iniciado sesión correctamente");
        this.router.navigateByUrl('/ruta/de/la/vista');
      } else {

        alert("Inicio de Sesión fallido");
      }
    }
  );
}
```

[Aquí](https://angular.io/guide/router) tienes toda la información sobre routing en angular.